# Jekyll Now GitHub Pages, Tables don't show up

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have a jekyll now website and I'm trying to put in some tables. They appear fine in github but not on the website. Here's a few snippets of table formatting that I've tried with no luck.

```
| P | Q | P * Q |
| - | - | - |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | F |
| F | F | F |

|====+====|
+====|====+
|=========|

|---|---|---|
|a  | b | c|
| 1|2|3|

|---+---+---|
+ :-: |:------| ---:|
| :-: :- -: -
:-: | :-

|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Default aligned |Left aligned| Center aligned  | Right aligned  |
|-----------------|:-----------|:---------------:|---------------:|
| First body part |Second cell | Third cell      | fourth cell    |
| Second line     |foo         | **strong**      | baz            |
| Third line      |quux        | baz             | bar            |
|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Second body     |            |                 |                |
| 2 line          |            |                 |                |
|=================+============+=================+================|
| Footer row      |            |                 |                |
|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
```

I'm using default settings with Jekyll Now, so markdown is Kramdown. I saw solutions from other stack overflow posts but they don't appear to work. Is there something wrong with my formatting or do I need to do something else to get it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to apply some styling to the [tables](https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables) code, for example to apply the css class `tablelines` you can use *inline attributes* `{: .tablelines}` :

```
<style>
.tablelines table, .tablelines td, .tablelines th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>

| P | Q | P * Q |
| - | - | - |
| T | T | T |
| T | F | F |
| F | T | F |
| F | F | F |
{: .tablelines}

|---|---|---|
|a  | b | c|
| 1|2|3|
{: .tablelines}

|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Default aligned |Left aligned| Center aligned  | Right aligned  |
|-----------------|:-----------|:---------------:|---------------:|
| First body part |Second cell | Third cell      | fourth cell    |
| Second line     |foo         | **strong**      | baz            |
| Third line      |quux        | baz             | bar            |
|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
| Second body     |            |                 |                |
| 2 line          |            |                 |                |
|=================+============+=================+================|
| Footer row      |            |                 |                |
|-----------------+------------+-----------------+----------------|
{: .tablelines}

| A simple | table |
| with multiple | lines|
{: .tablelines}
```

Output using kramdown:

[image]

```
<style>
.tablelines table, .tablelines td, .tablelines th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        }
</style>

<table class="tablelines">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>P</th>
      <th>Q</th>
      <th>P * Q</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>T</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>F</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tablelines">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>c</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="tablelines">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Default aligned</th>
      <th style="text-align: left">Left aligned</th>
      <th style="text-align: center">Center aligned</th>
      <th style="text-align: right">Right aligned</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>First body part</td>
      <td style="text-align: left">Second cell</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">Third cell</td>
      <td style="text-align: right">fourth cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Second line</td>
      <td style="text-align: left">foo</td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><strong>strong</strong></td>
      <td style="text-align: right">baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Third line</td>
      <td style="text-align: left">quux</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">baz</td>
      <td style="text-align: right">bar</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Second body</td>
      <td style="text-align: left"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: center"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: right"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2 line</td>
      <td style="text-align: left"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: center"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: right"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Footer row</td>
      <td style="text-align: left"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: center"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: right"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<table class="tablelines">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A simple</td>
      <td>table</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>with multiple</td>
      <td>lines</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. Works great!

Comment: @marcanuy In my case, the table can be shown on github preview page, but canot be shown when I enter my github website by typing my github addreee on browser address bar. As you said, do I have to add css style on each post and add `{: .tablelines}` under the table of each post?

Comment: @frank there should be another problem then, the above method should work without problems, considering posting it in its own question here with your code if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/barryclark/jekyll-now/issues/561) GitHub issue the problem is missing styles for tables. As suggested in the ticket try to add table style from here: https://gist.github.com/andyferra/2554919

Comment: add the styles for tables to where/which file?